# AppWidget update once a minute

Tags: android, widget, alarmmanager, android-appwidget

I have an Android AppWidget that I would like to update once a minute. So in The `AppWidgetProvider` I create a repeating alarm set to trigger once every 60 seconds. At first it seems fine. For the first 10 minutes or so it updates almost exactly once a minute. But then it slows down and only updates about every 3-5 minutes. I'm wondering if this is an issue with the way I have the AppWidget set up, or if I'm initializing the timer incorrectly. It also doesn't seem to update in regular intervals after the slow down.

**AppWidgetProvider**

```
private PendingIntent service = null;

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context,
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    startAlarm(context);
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    startAlarm(context);
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    // TODO: disable alarm
}

private void startAlarm(Context context) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Starting alarm");

    final AlarmManager m =
        (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    final Intent i = new Intent(context, MyService.class);

    if (service == null)
        service = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    m.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 10),
            1000 * 60, service);
}
```

**MyService**

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Service started");
    buildUpdate();

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

private void buildUpdate() {

    // Do stuff.

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

This is being run on my Samsung Galaxy S7 API level 23 if that is relevant. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your targetSdkVersion? Beginning with API 19 (Kitkat) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use.

For exact alarms, in case your targetSdkVersion is 19 or later, you have to use `setExact(...)`. There is no exact version of `setRepeating(...)`

For Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 `setRepeating(...)` will still deliver exact alarms.

Comment: Wonderful, don't know how I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually if you need update widget more than one time per 30 mins, the best approach to use *IntentService* that will update your widget (alarm on it). Same approach i use at my [library](https://github.com/HeyAlex/WidgetUpdateHelper) for widgets which i use on internal and my projects (since it's gonna like a *pattern* which i can use on every project with widgets). Actually i didn't find any problems with your code (maybe you can make a small sample project from your code).